# How do I create a Windows desktop app from UWP code

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, .net-4.5, .net-core

I have an existing project for Windows 10 (UWP).
It creates an app that can go into Windows Store and be sideloaded, and that works fine.

... but now I would like to create a desktop-version (an exe-file) from the same code base (to avoid sideload-security issues in local network).
I created a VS 2015 4.5.2 WPF project and started to reference the components (dll's) used in the UWP project. But the importer states that some of the components depends on .Net-Core, and cannot be referenced.

So: Is it possible to mix .NET-Core and .NET-Framework components in the same WPF project?

Or: Can I create a .Net-Core console-app, create the used windows, use XAML, and export an exe (with dependencies) that can run standalone?

Thx!

Comment: Since you can't just mix .net-Core and .net-Framework in a single Application, there is not really a way to use the same codebase.

Comment: Try this link https://mtaulty.com/2016/10/28/windows-10-1607-uwp-screencast-of-a-wpf-app-calling-uwp-apis-withwithout-an-appx-package/ . I never tried it but it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately what you are tying to achieve is not possible.

UWP and WPF are different stacks and unless you are using PCLs code cannot be shared between them.
Even then, the XAML layer is different and not compatible from one stack to another.
So no, you cannot reuse your code in a WPF application

As for the other solution, you cannot have your UWP app run as an .exe because Universal Apps run a different Application Model called appx which is fundamentally different than the exe application model. 
There are ways to wrap an exe application in an appx (See the Desktop App Converter) but there is no converter/repackager to take you from appx to exe.